# Android: How to enable printing to android console in external java library?

Tags: java, android

I'm using an external java library in my android project. Now I want to print stuff inside this library to the android debugging console.

The java library is linked via `build.gradle` as follows:

```
[...]
dpendencies {
    implementation project(path: ':MyCustomJavaLibrary')
}
```

Simply using `System.out.println("My Message");` does compile, but the message does not appear in the corresponding debug console.
Moreover I cannot use Android `Log.d("...")` inside the Java library.

Comment: You can use SLFJ4 logger for Android: http://www.slf4j.org/android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (taken from a related Stackoverflow answer)

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyClass{
    private final Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
    private final Level log_level = java.util.logging.Level.INFO;
    [...]
    logger.log(log_level, "Start track_pose");
    [...]
}
```